# Jaxb, Class has two properties of the same name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

With Jaxb (jaxb-impl-2.1.12), UI try to read [an XML file](http://www.copypastecode.com/75029/)

Only a few element in the XML file are interesting, so I would like to skip most of the elements.

The XML I'm trying to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2010 rel. 3 sp1 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<flx:ModeleREP xsi:schemaLocation="urn:test:mod_rep.xsd mod_rep.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:flx="urn:test:mod_rep.xsd">
<flx:DocumentHeader>
    <flx:Identification v="04489"/>
</flx:DocumentHeader>
<flx:TimeSeries>
    <flx:Identification v="test1a"/>
    <flx:BusinessType v="A01"/>
    <flx:Product v="123a"/>
    <flx:ResourceObject codingScheme="N" v="testa"/>
    <flx:Period>
        <flx:TimeInterval v="2011-07-02T00:00/2011-07-16T00:00"/>
        <flx:Resolution v="PT2H"/>
        <flx:Pt>
            <flx:P v="1"/>
            <flx:Q unitCode="String" v="1.0"/>
            <flx:A currencyIdentifier="String" v="195.0"/>
        </flx:Pt>
    </flx:Period>
</flx:TimeSeries>
<flx:TimeSeries>
    <flx:Identification v="test2a"/>
    <flx:BusinessType v="A01"/>
    <flx:Product v="a123b"/>
    <flx:ResourceObject codingScheme="N" v="test2"/>
    <flx:Period>
        <flx:TimeInterval v="2011-07-02T00:00/2011-07-16T00:00"/>
        <flx:Resolution v="PT2H"/>
        <flx:Pt>
            <flx:P v="1"/>
            <flx:Q unitCode="String" v="1.0"/>
            <flx:A currencyIdentifier="String" v="195.0"/>
        </flx:Pt>
        <flx:Pt>
            <flx:P v="2"/>
            <flx:Q unitCode="String" v="1.0"/>
            <flx:A currencyIdentifier="String" v="195.0"/>
        </flx:Pt>
    </flx:Period>
</flx:TimeSeries>
</flx:ModeleREP>
```

my class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ModeleREP", namespace="urn:test:mod_rep.xsd")
public class ModeleREP {

  @XmlElement(name="TimeSeries")
  protected List<TimeSeries> timeSeries;

  public List<TimeSeries> getTimeSeries() {
  if (this.timeSeries == null) {
      this.timeSeries = new ArrayList<TimeSeries>();
  }
  return this.timeSeries;
  }

  public void setTimeSeries(List<TimeSeries> timeSeries) {
  this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
  }

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TimeSeries")
public class TimeSeries {

@XmlElement(name="ResourceObject")
protected RessourceObject resourceObject;

@XmlElement(name = "Period")
protected Period period;

public RessourceObject getResourceObject() {
    return this.resourceObject;
}

public void setResourceObject(RessourceObject resourceObject) {
    this.resourceObject = resourceObject;
}

public Period getPeriod() {
    return this.period;
}

public void setPeriod(Period period) {
    this.period = period;
}

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ResourceObject")

public class RessourceObject {
@XmlAttribute(name = "codingScheme")
protected String codingScheme;

@XmlAttribute(name = "v")
protected String v;

public String getCodingScheme() {
    return this.codingScheme;
}

public void setCodingScheme(String codingScheme) {
    this.codingScheme = codingScheme;
}

public String getV() {
    return this.v;
}

public void setV(String v) {
    this.v = v;
}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Period")
public class Period {

@XmlElement(name = "TimeInterval")
protected TimeInterval timeInterval;

@XmlElement(name = "Pt")
protected List<Pt> pt;

public TimeInterval getTimeInterval() {
    return this.timeInterval;
}

public void setTimeInterval(TimeInterval timeInterval) {
    this.timeInterval = timeInterval;
}

public List<Pt> getPt() {
    if (this.pt == null) {
    this.pt = new ArrayList<Pt>();
    }
    return this.pt;
}

public void setPt(List<Pt> pt) {
    this.pt=pt;
}

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TimeInterval")
public class TimeInterval {

@XmlAttribute(name = "v")
private String timeIntervalPeriod;

public String getTimeIntervalPeriod() {
    return this.timeIntervalPeriod;
}

public void setTimeIntervalPeriod(String timeIntervalPeriod) {
    this.timeIntervalPeriod = timeIntervalPeriod;
}

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Pt")
public class Pt {

@XmlElement(name = "P")
protected P p;

@XmlElement(name = "A")
protected A a;

public P getP() {
    return this.p;
}

public void setP(P p) {
    this.p = p;
}

public A getA() {
    return this.a;
}

public void setA(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "P")
public class P {
@XmlAttribute(name = "v")
protected String position;


public String getPosition(){
    return this.position;
}

public void setPosition(String position){
    this.position=position;
}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {
@XmlAttribute(name = "v")
protected String calculatedAmount;

public String getCalculatedAmount() {
    return this.calculatedAmount;
}

public void setCalculatedAmount(String calculatedAmount) {
    this.calculatedAmount = calculatedAmount;
}
}
```

when I try to read the XML file, I get this error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "timeSeries"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.getTimeSeries()
        at testjaxp.ModeleREP
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.timeSeries
        at testjaxp.ModeleREP
```

I don't understand this error. And sometimes when I check my object, timeSeries is null.

How can I fix this error/prevent timeSeries from returning null?

Answer (score 259):

I set these properties when I faced this problem. Setting one or both of them may solve your issue:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="yourRootElementName")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

Comment: I had the same issue. And even it works when we add only @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

Comment: I solved the issue by _removing_ the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation

Comment: Sounds strange, but I also got rid of this exception by reducing pair of annotations 
    \@XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
to only 
    \@XmlRootElement

Comment: I had that issue with ```@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)``` and changing it to ```@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)``` solved the problem

Answer (score 29):

There are multiple solutions: If you annotate on variable declaration then you need `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, but if you prefer to annotate either a get- or set-method then you don't.

So you can do:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MY_CLASS_A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClassA
{
    @XmlElement(name = "STATUS")   
    private int status;
   //.. and so on
}
```

Or:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MY_CLASS_A")
public class MyClassA
{
    private int status;
      
    @XmlElement(name = "STATUS")         
    public int getStatus()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You didn't specified what JAXB-IMPL version are you using, but once I had the same problem (with jaxb-impl 2.0.5) and solved it using the annotation at the getter level instead of using it at the member level.

Comment: That is correct I just removed the annotation from member and put it on setter level and it worked.

Answer (score 25):

I've also seen some similiar issues like this.

I think, it's because of the *place* where we use the "**@XMLElement**" ***annotation*** in the (bean) class.

And I think, the *JAXB* (annotation processor) considers the member field & getter method of the same field element as different properties, when we use the  **@XMLElement** annotation at the **field** level and throws the *IllegalAnnotationExceptions* exception.

Exception Message :

> Class has **two properties** of the ***same*** *name* "timeSeries"

At Getter Method :

> ```
>     at public java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.getTimeSeries()
> ```

At Member Field :

> ```
>     at protected java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.timeSeries
> ```

*Solution :*
Instead of using ***@XmlElement*** in the **field**, use it in the **getter** method.

Comment: can confirm this is my problem, after removing the lombok @Getter then it works

Answer (score 20):

just added this to my class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

worked like a cham

Comment: This just repeats the [top answer from March 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768544/jaxb-class-has-two-properties-of-the-same-name/15330184#15330184) (except gives half as much information), 4 years prior. Please only add new answers when you have _new_ information to give.

Answer (score 11):

Your JAXB is looking at both the `getTimeSeries()` method and the member `timeSeries`. You don't say which JAXB implementation you're using, or its configuration, but the exception is fairly clear.

> at public java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.getTimeSeries()

and

> at protected java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.timeSeries

You need to configure you JAXB stuff to use annotations (as per your `@XmlElement(name="TimeSeries")`) and ignore public methods.

Comment: i already do: @XmlElement(name="TimeSeries")
              protected List<TimeSeries> timeSeries;

Comment: also i change (XmlAccessType.FIELD) to (XmlAccessType.NONE), i can keep XmlElement at the member level

Comment: I also needed to add @XmlTransient to the variable

Answer (score 10):

***"Class has two properties of the same name exception"*** can happen when you have a class member x with a public access level and a getter/setter for the same member.

As a java rule of thumb, it is not recommended to use a **public** access level together with getters and setters.

Check this for more details: 
[Public property VS Private property with getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002928/public-property-vs-private-property-with-getter)

To fix that:

1. Change your member's access level to **private** and keep your getter/setter
2. Remove the member's getter and setter

Answer (score 9):

If we use the below annotations and remove the "@XmlElement" annotation, code should work properly and resultant XML would have the element names similar to the class member.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="<RootElementName>")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

In case use of "@XmlElement" is really required, please define it as field level and code should work perfectly. Don't define the annotation on the top of getter method.

Had tried both the above approaches mentioned and got to fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

You need to configure class `ModeleREP` as well with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` as you did with class `TimeSeries`.

Have al look at [OOXS](https://web.archive.org/web/20130308074323/http://ooxs-be.goracer.nl/EN/java/Java%20and%20XML%20Binding.html)

Answer (score 8):

Declare the member variables to private in the class you want to convert to XML.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. If you declare your member variable public, JABX will parse it in addition to getter/setter annotated methods and spit the exception.

It's a great example where jabx library designer(s) went an extra mile on reflection trying to create flexibility and ended up facilitating invalid configurations. I fixed the problem on my own by changing one line of code at the time, tracing back to the member variable.

Answer (score 7):

These are the two properties JAXB is looking at.

```
public java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.getTimeSeries()
```

and

```
protected java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.timeSeries
```

This can be avoided by using JAXB annotation at get method just like mentioned below.

```
@XmlElement(name="TimeSeries"))  
public java.util.List testjaxp.ModeleREP.getTimeSeries()
```

Answer (score 3):

It will work when you put your annotation before the getters, and remove it from the protected attributes:

```
protected String codingScheme;

@XmlAttribute(name = "codingScheme")
public String getCodingScheme() {
    return this.codingScheme;
}
```

Comment: I too am running into the same problem. I too have observed that when the annotation is marked over the attributes I see this. Does this mean that always it should be placed before the getters?.

Comment: @Pavan Yes I think so. Otherwise, it causes me the same problems than you

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is that you have both XmlAccessType.FIELD and pairs of getters and setters. The solution is to remove setters and add a default constructor and a constructor that takes all fields.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and simple way to fix this issue is to remove the `@XmlElement(name="TimeSeries")` from the top of the variable declaration statement `protected List<TimeSeries> timeSeries;` to the top of its getter,  `public List<TimeSeries> getTimeSeries()`.

Thus your `ModeleREP`  class will look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ModeleREP", namespace="urn:test:mod_rep.xsd")
public class ModeleREP {


  protected List<TimeSeries> timeSeries;

  @XmlElement(name="TimeSeries")
  public List<TimeSeries> getTimeSeries() {
    if (this.timeSeries == null) {
      this.timeSeries = new ArrayList<TimeSeries>();
    }
    return this.timeSeries;
  }

  public void setTimeSeries(List<TimeSeries> timeSeries) {
    this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention 'A simple way'. Curious, is there any other way out of this - nay other annotation that could be leveraged?.

Answer (score 1):

I had a service class with a signature as below:

```
@WebMethod
public FetchIQAStatusResponseVO fetchIQAStatus(FetchIQAStatusRequest fetchIQAStatusRequest) {
```

On run I got the same error for `FetchIQAStatusResponseVO` fields. I just added a line on top of `FetchIQAStatusResponseVO`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) //This line added
public class FetchIQAStatusResponseVO {
```

and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ModeleREP#getTimeSeries()` have to be with `@Transient` annotation. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

Annotating with `@XmlTransient` resolves that issue

```
@XmlTransient
public void setTimeSeries(List<TimeSeries> timeSeries) {
   this.timeSeries = timeSeries;
}
```

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html for more details

Comment: I think this is more a hack than a solution. This tells jaxb to ignore the method, instead of making it aware that it is the same thing.

Comment: Hack or not this IS the best solution to get around something that can't be described as anything short of a bug, I used @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) which was mostly ignored and adding @XmlTransient to each property was the only way to repair this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions have been given, and the internals are briefly touched by @Sriram and @ptomli as well. I just want to add a few references to the source code to help understand what is happening under the hood.

By default (i.e. no extra annotations used at all except `@XmlRootElement` on the root class), JABX tries to marshal things exposed via two ways:

1. public [fields](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/83985e41faded5c5fe48877c0abfa2c6c70c3b27/jaxws/src/share/jaxws_classes/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/model/impl/ClassInfoImpl.java#L296)
2. [getter methods](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/83985e41faded5c5fe48877c0abfa2c6c70c3b27/jaxws/src/share/jaxws_classes/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/model/impl/ClassInfoImpl.java#L298) that are named following the [convention](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/83985e41faded5c5fe48877c0abfa2c6c70c3b27/jaxws/src/share/jaxws_classes/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/model/impl/ClassInfoImpl.java#L1154) and have a corresponding setter method.

Notice that if a field is (or method returns) `null`, it will not be written into the output.

Now if `@XmlElement` is used, non-public things (could be fields or getter methods) can be marshalled as well.

But the two ways, i.e. fields and getter-methods, must not conflict with each other. Otherwise you get [the exception](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/83985e41faded5c5fe48877c0abfa2c6c70c3b27/jaxws/src/share/jaxws_classes/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.java#L445).