# How do you specify the date format used when JAXB marshals xsd:dateTime?

Tags: datetime, jaxb, format, marshalling, milliseconds

When JAXB marshals a date object (`XMLGregorianCalendar`) into an xsd:dateTime element. How can you specify the format of the resulting XML?

For example:
The default data format uses milliseconds `<StartDate>2012-08-21T13:21:58.000Z</StartDate>`
I need to omit the milliseconds.  `<StartDate>2012-08-21T13:21:58Z</StartDate>`

How can I specify the output form/date format that I want it to use?
I'm using `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory` to create the `XMLGregorianCalendar` object.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = datatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` to customize how a date type is written to XML.

```java
package com.example;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to specify that the `XmlAdapter` should be used for a specific field/property.

```java
@XmlElement(name = "timestamp", required = true) 
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
protected Date timestamp;
```

Using a xjb binding file:

```
<xjc:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
        adapter="com.example.DateAdapter"/>
```

will produce the above mentioned annotation.
(By eventually adding the `xjc` namespace: `xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"`)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Is it possible to add the annotation via the xsd or a binding file? I only found your frequently quoted blog entry about bindings.xml, but this covers other aspects, I think.

Comment: As @PeterRader mentioned, SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe - if two threads were to enter either marshal or unmarshal simultaneously, you could get very unpredictable results. This would be very difficult to reproduce in normal testing, but under load could happen, and would be exceedingly difficult to diagnose. It's better to create a new SimpleDateFormat with marshal and unmarshal (but use a static format string if necessary).

Comment: I did this and it almost worked. However I was getting `Class has two properties of the same name "timeSeries"` error - this was solved by putting the annotation at the getter and not at the member level. (Thanks to @megathor from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768544/jaxb-class-has-two-properties-of-the-same-name)

Comment: @gordon613 - This article will provide some additional information on where to put the annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Since the critical block is protected with "synchronized" there is not any problem. There will be (performance) problem if multiple calls are made.

Comment: This solution does not work when the classes are generated from XSD.

Comment: There is something wrong/missing with the XJB file part. There is no `parseDateTime` and `formatDateTime` provided in the DateAdapter above. I tried to use `marshal` and `unmarshal` instead, but I end up with the error `non-static method marshal(java.util.Date) cannot be referenced from a static context` when I compile my code. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: how to add milliseconds optional?

Comment: The xjb binding does not produce the mentioned annotation.

Answer (score 21):

I use a SimpleDateFormat to create the XMLGregorianCalendar, such as in this example:

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlDate(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
}

public static XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlDateTime(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(date));
}
```

The first method creates an instance of XMLGregorianCalendar that is formatted by the XML marshaller as a valid xsd:date, the second method results in a valid xsd:dateTime.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy way to me. Formatting XMLGregorianCalendar for marshalling in java.

I just create my data in the good format. The `toString` will be called producing the good result.

```
public static final XMLGregorianCalendar getDate(Date d) {
    try {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d));
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormat 
      = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {

        @Override
        protected DateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.get().parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.get().format(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```java
import com.company.LocalDateAdapter.yyyyMMdd;

//...

@XmlElement(name = "PROC-DATE")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(yyyyMMdd.class)
private LocalDate processingDate;
```

LocalDateAdapter

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

  public static final class yyyyMMdd extends LocalDateAdapter {
    public yyyyMMdd() {
      super("yyyyMMdd");
    }
  }

  public static final class yyyy_MM_dd extends LocalDateAdapter {
    public yyyy_MM_dd() {
      super("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
  }

  private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

  public LocalDateAdapter(String pattern) {
    formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(LocalDate date) throws Exception {
    return formatter.print(date);
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate unmarshal(String date) throws Exception {
    return formatter.parseLocalDate(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Question not about LocalDate but XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: @krund question is about 'How can you specify the format of the resulting XML?'. You have an example how to do it, replace the date code import for the one you need.

Comment: OP mentioned XMLGregorianCalendar, so this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376876/6860091 response solved problem for me.

Comment: @krund good for you