# JAXB dateTime format after XML generation

Tags: java, xml, date, jaxb

I have short question:

After xjc class generation from xsd, my object require Calendar and thats what I supply. But after marshalling it to XML my date format is as follows:

```
<InfoDateTime v="2013-09-03T00:00:00+02:00"/>
```

whereas I would like to have:

```
<InfoDateTime v="2013-09-03T00:00:00Z"/>
```

I do not use annotated jaxb but with binding file but is it possible without creating classes which can parse date and string?

Thanks!

Comment: The Date formatter `toString()` will output the date using the current time zone. Depending where your `v` is generated, you could override the `toString()` method to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `Calendar` you can set the `TimeZone` you wish to use:

### Java Model

**Root**

Below is a simple Java object that has 2 mapped `Calendar` fields.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    Calendar defaultTimeZone;
    Calendar setTimeZone;

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will create two instances of `Calendar` on `defaultTimeZone` it will have the default time zone (my environment is Canada/Eastern) and on `setTimeZone` we will specify GMT.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.defaultTimeZone = Calendar.getInstance();

        root.setTimeZone = Calendar.getInstance();
        root.setTimeZone.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <defaultTimeZone>2013-09-03T09:40:59.443-04:00</defaultTimeZone>
    <setTimeZone>2013-09-03T13:40:59.443Z</setTimeZone>
</root>
```

Comment: well, I dont know why but my output looks like :  v="2013-09-03T22:00:00+00:00"/> when I set timezone to GMT

Comment: @xwhyz - Which implementation and version of JAXB are you using?

Comment: @xwhyz - Are you just picking up the JAXB included in your JDK or application server?

Comment: Im using it for a long time with my other xsd files and had no problem, but now I have requirement to change date format

Comment: I've seen that the "Z" vs. "+00:00" varies with the jars you pick up. I'm using SimpleDateFormat with XXXX vs. ZZZZ to force the text to not vary from one environment to another. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568543/how-do-you-specify-the-date-format-used-when-jaxb-marshals-xsddatetime for details on how to setup your own formatter. The text changing like that has an impact on XML digital signing.