# JAXB - Creating Custom Serializers without modifying jaxb classes

Tags: java, jaxb

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568543/how-do-you-specify-the-date-format-used-when-jaxb-marshals-xsddatetime) for setting custom date format while serializing a java object into xml. In my case the class files are present inside a jar that I cannot modify. Is there a way to add a custom serializer without modifying the existing classes? Thanks.

Comment: Seems your title does not really match your question. I suggest you edit to clarify either way.

Comment: @BasilBourque : Thanks , edited the subject. hope it is better.

Comment: It is not possible without specifying `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. But if you are using `moxy`, check this [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html)