# Validating amounts and dates in RestService CXF 3, jaxrs

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I have CXF rest service and passing amounts and dates in MyRequest. I somebody passess 'abc' in amount or 'abc' in mydate then some internal cxf exceptions occurs. I want to have my own classes validating values of amount and mydate and throw my custom exceptions. Is it possible? I know that in webservices there are some datatype adapters but in REST i cant see any examples on CXF documentation.

```
  @POST
    @Path( "/myMethod" )
    void myMethod(MyRequest request);

MyRequest{
private BigDecimal amount;
private Date mydate;

//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't use any other frameworks, you will do the conversion/validation step by hand. What I normally do is to accept such arguments as String as every input and output are initially strings. Later I try to convert them into the objects that I need. So I propose the following:

```
MyRequest{
    private String amount;
    private String mydate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And in the controller:

```
void myMethod(MyRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        BigDecimal bigDecimalAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(request.getAmount()));
    }
    catch(Exception exception
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Further if you use a framework like Spring, you may want to look at how custom validators can be implemented.

Comment: I use cxf and I cant change api, I need an answer specific to cxf / jaxrs

Comment: I meant that you might use some more frameworks. You don't have to.Spring e.g. would try to convert these arguments into the corresponding  classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some alternatives:

1- If you have an XML schema you can use JAXB validation with a custom `MessageBodyReader`. See [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)

2- You can use JAXB `XMLAdapter` to customize how a data type is read and mapped to an object. See [How do you specify the date format used when JAXB marshals xsd:dateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568543/how-do-you-specify-the-date-format-used-when-jaxb-marshals-xsddatetime)

You have to annotate the properties

```
@XmlRootElement
 public class MyRequest{

     @XmlElement(name = "mydate", required = true) 
     @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
     protected Date mydate;
```

And define the XmlAdapter

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
```

This solution is applicable to XML data and also to JSON using Jackson mapper because some of the JAXB annotations are supported deserializing data. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

To configure jackson with jaxb provider in CXF see https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson

```
 <jaxrs:providers>
      <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
 </jaxrs:providers>
```