# JAX-RS Request Custom date format

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, simpledateformat

How to consume a java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp from JSON request in JAX-RS?

I pass the Request on the POST URL  http://localhost:8080/jaxrs/webapi/students/ to add a new student to the database. Created AT date is passed in yyyy-mm-dd format. But JAX-RS is not able to convert the format and initialize the Student object. Adding the request sample, Student class and the Student Resource

```
{
    "createdAt": "2018-45-05",
    "name": "Minne"
}
```

Student Class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date createdAt;
....
```

Create Student Resource Method

```
@Path("/students")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StudentRes {

    @POST
    public Student addStudent(Student student) {
        student.setId(students.size() + 1);
        students.put(student.getId(), stude
    }
```

The error I get is

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/jaxrs] threw exception [javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.] with root cause
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-45-05' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1775)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DateTypeDeserializer.parseDefault(DateTypeDeserializer.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDateTimeDeserializer.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractValueTypeDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectDeserializer.deserializeNext(ObjectDeserializer.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueParamProvider$EntityValueSupplier.apply(EntityParamValueParamProvider.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you specify the date format used when JAXB marshals xsd:dateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568543/how-do-you-specify-the-date-format-used-when-jaxb-marshals-xsddatetime)

Comment: its not a good practice to use java.sql library's data-types in a service request/response model. you should separate layers. java.sql.Date/Timestamp commonly used in JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `private Date createdAt` in your Student POJO class, you can change that to `private String createdAt`. Now you can have a method that converts the String type date to your required type `java.sql.Date` as shown below:

```
public java.sql.Date convertToDate(String date)
{
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
        return sqlDate;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. This will work. But I'm looking if there is something better available where Jackson does the conversion internally and I do not need to handle it. I guess @XmlJavaTypeAdapter should work. I will test that out and reply on this thread.