# Unable to get the value of a parameter starting with capital letter while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I'm trying to use unmarshalling to create an object using xml string. This is the code that I'm using. But I'm unable to get the value of a parameter(MemResponse) that is not in camelcase, rest parameters are getting set properly.

Earlier I was not using the jsonproperty annotation, I googled for this issue and got to know about this annotation. However, after using the annotation also. MemResponse field is still getting null value.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transaction.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(content));
JAXBElement<Transaction> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, Transaction.class);
```

The transaction class is as follows

```
public class Transaction
{
    private String transType;

    private String xmlDate;

    private String source;

    private String xmlVersion;

    @JsonProperty("MemResponse")
    private MemResponse MemResponse;
}
```

This is the MemResponse class

```
public class MemResponse
{
    @JsonProperty("DependantDetail")
    private DependantDetail[] DependantDetail;

    @JsonProperty("Telephone")
    private Telephone Telephone;

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private Address[] Address;

    @JsonProperty("MemberDetail")
    private MemberDetail MemberDetail;
}
```

This is my sml string

```
<Transaction>\n  
    <xmlVersion>1</xmlVersion>\n
    <xmlDate>25/11/2011</xmlDate>\n
    <source>MACROMOBI</source>\n
    <transType>MEMDETAIL</transType>\n
    <MemResponse>\n    
        <MemberDetail>\n      
            <joinDate>01/07/2007</joinDate>\n
            <leftDate>31/01/2008</leftDate>\n
            <employerCode></employerCode>\n
            <depCount>2</depCount>\n
            <langPref>ENG</langPref>\n
            <nextMemberNo/>\n
            <nextPlanCode/>\n
        </MemberDetail>\n
        <DependantDetail>\n      
            <depNum>01</depNum>\n
            <initials>G</initials>\n
            <depTitle>MR</depTitle>\n
            <gender>M</gender>\n
            <maritalStatus>S</maritalStatus>\n
            <joinDate>01/07/2007</joinDate>\n
            <leftDate>31/01/2008</leftDate>\n
            <relation>SELF</relation>\n
            <depType>PM</depType>\n
        </DependantDetail>\n
        <DependantDetail>\n      
            <depNum>02</depNum>\n
            <initials>S</initials>\n
            <depTitle>MRS</depTitle>\n
            <birthDate>20/11/1944</birthDate>\n
            <gender>F</gender>\n
            <maritalStatus>S</maritalStatus>\n
            <joinDate>01/07/2007</joinDate>\n
            <benefitStart>01/07/2007</benefitStart>\n
            <leftDate>31/01/2008</leftDate>\n
        </DependantDetail>\n
        <Telephone>\n      
            <contType>MVWORK</contType>\n
            <dialCode>+</dialCode>\n
            <dialNum>5</dialNum>\n
            <smsFlag/>\n
        </Telephone>\n
        <Address>\n      
            <contType>PM</contType>\n
            <addr02>MORNINGSIDE</addr02>\n
            <addr04/>\n
            <town>MUTARE</town>\n
            <postCode>0000</postCode>\n
        </Address>\n
        <Address>\n      
            <contType>RM</contType>\n
            <addr02>MORNINGSIDE</addr02>\n
            <addr03>MUTARE</addr03>\n
            <addr04/>\n
            <postCode>0000</postCode>\n
        </Address>\n
    </MemResponse>\n
</Transaction>\n
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `@JsonProperty` to deserialize your transaction object because you are dealing with XML and `@JsonProperty` is specific to JSON.

Instead, put an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your `Transaction` class, and an `@XmlElement` annotation on all fields.  Below is what your `Transaction` class should look like, I'll leave it up to you to make the same changes to `MemResponse` and other classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Transaction {
    @XmlElement
    private String transType;

    @XmlElement
    private String xmlDate;

    @XmlElement
    private String source;

    @XmlElement
    private String xmlVersion;

    @XmlElement(name = "MemResponse")
    private MemResponse memResponse;
}
```

You don't have to specify the `name` within the `@XmlElement` annotation if the element name matches the field name.  However, as an example, I've given the `memResponse` field an initial lower-case letter, to fit with the Java naming convention for fields, and specified that this should use the element name `MemResponse` in the annotation.

Comment: just to add to the above answer, I was getting the following error after the xmlRootElement annotation - "Class has two properties of the same name" 

This solved the issue however - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768544/jaxb-class-has-two-properties-of-the-same-name

Comment: @uGONNAdie glad you fixed that problem, but I didn't get that with the code you provided in your question.